# Devise LDAP can't find user, but logs in fine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ldap

So when I authorize a user with the [devise_ldap_authenticatable gem](https://github.com/cschiewek/devise_ldap_authenticatable), I get the following logged information:

```
  LDAP: LDAP dn lookup: sAMAccountName=john.smith
  LDAP: LDAP search for login: sAMAccountName=john.smith
  LDAP: LDAP search yielded 0 matches
  LDAP: Authorizing user lt\john.smith
```

As I understand it, the search fails to return a user, which I would like to find so I could set other attributes based off of LDAP fields (mainly `department`).

I've checked that this search should work with the following rake task:

```
desc "LDAP Test"
  task ldap: :environment do
    ldap = Net::LDAP.new :host => ENV['LDAP_IP'],
                         :port => ENV['LDAP_PORT'],
                         :encryption => :simple_tls,
                         :base => ENV['LDAP_BASE'],
                         :auth => {
                             :method => :simple,
                             :username => ENV['LDAP_LOGIN'],
                             :password => ENV['LDAP_PASSWORD']
                         }
    if ldap.bind
      ldap.search(:base => ENV['LDAP_BASE'], :filter => Net::LDAP::Filter.eq("sAMAccountName", "john.smith"), :attributes => ["sAMAccountName", "department"], :return_result => false) do |entry|
        entry.each do |attr, values|
          puts "#{attr}: #{values.first}"
        end
      end
    else
      puts "Connection failed!  Code:  #{ldap.get_operation_result.code}, message: #{ldap.get_operation_result.message}"
    end
  end
```

Which returns:

```
dn: CN=John Smith,OU=Temporary Staff,OU=Users,DC=lt,DC=local
department: Bioinformatics
samaccountname: Johh.Smith
```

Does anyone know why the login search could be failing? My config files are as follows:

**devise.rb:**

```
# ==> LDAP Configuration 
  config.ldap_logger = true
  config.ldap_create_user = true
  config.ldap_update_password = false
  # config.ldap_config = "#{Rails.root}/config/ldap.yml"
  config.ldap_auth_username_builder = Proc.new() {|attribute, login, ldap| "lt\\#{login}"}
  # config.ldap_check_group_membership = false
  # config.ldap_check_attributes = false
  config.ldap_use_admin_to_bind = true
```

**ldap.yml:**

```
development:
  host: <%= ENV['LDAP_IP'] %>
  port: <%= ENV['LDAP_PORT'] %>
  attribute: sAMAccountName
  base: <%= ENV['LDAP_BASE'] %>
  admin_user: <%= ENV['LDAP_LOGIN'] %>
  admin_password: <%= ENV['LDAP_PASSWORD'] %>
  ssl: true
  # <<: *AUTHORIZATIONS
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a packet sniffer like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to see the difference between the LDAP requests in the rake task vs. devise. The [UnboundID LDAP SDK for Java](https://docs.ldap.com/ldap-sdk/docs/examples/) also ships with a tool called LDAPDebugger that you can use as a proxy between your app and Active Directory to decode the traffic.

I hope this helps.